# Can I expense rental costs for tax purposes?

Tags: tax-law

I currently own a property in the UK, which is where I currently live and plan on living most of the time. However, I have recently accepted a job in France and will need to rent accommodation for this purpose.

Q: can I expense the cost of the accommodation in France, and also the cost of my travel back and forth from France?

On the one hand, these are business expenses in the sense that I would not incur them if I were not doing this job. So one might think they can be expensed. On the other hand, people cannot generally expense rental costs even if they have moved to an area for the purposes of work. Perhaps the fact that my primary residence would remain in the UK could make the difference?

Comment: Which tax regime? UK or France? "Living most of the time" in the UK suggests the former.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If it is a business expense, yes

It depends on the nature of the "job".

If you run a business based in the UK and the job is a contract to your business, then the costs involved in performing the work are tax deductible.

If you are an employee and the base location of your job is in France, then these are personal expenses and not tax deducatable.